# How to stay logged in for Android

Tags: java, android

Below is my SavedSharePreference class:

```
public class SaveSharedPreference {
    static final String PREF_USER_NAME= "username";

    static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context ctx) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    }

    public static void setUserName(Context ctx, String userName)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
        editor.putString(PREF_USER_NAME, userName);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static String getUserName(Context ctx)
    {
        return getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(PREF_USER_NAME, "");
    }
}
```

And users have to login from the MainActivity.java. The if/else statement below is inside the onCreate method.

```
if(SaveSharedPreference.getUserName(MainActivity.this).length() == 0)
        {
            b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
            et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
            pass= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
            tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        }
        else
        {
            // Call Next Activity
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserPage.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("username",et.getText().toString().trim());
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
```

Everytime I close the app and opens it again, I would need to login again. How should I modify the code to make it to stay logged in ?

Comment: Please provide more information. Where are you calling `setUserName()`?

Comment: Try saying `getApplicationContext()` rather than `MainActivity.this` inside the `if` statement.

Comment: where do you call "setUserName"

Comment: In my login method right after php response "user found" @HeshanSandeepa

Comment: yep, which activity or class ?

Comment: @HeshanSandeepa in my mainactivity's class. It keeps crashing

Comment: post how you call that method ...